# How to find child's pom that are affected by parent's pom change?

Tags: maven, maven-3

If I have a lot of child projects which inherit pom from parent pom which contains the `dependencyManagement`, what is ***maven way*** of figuring out which child's pom need to be updated if the parent's pom version is changed because of some changes in the `dependencyManagement`.

I'm looking for what is the best way to do it with maven itself without resolving to manual search like grepping through all child's poms to see which one affected.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using [`mvn versions:update-parent`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-parent-mojo.html), which updates the parent version to the latest version.

See http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/update-parent.html for an example.

Comment: I know the pom's dependency declaration is from child to parent. Is there a plugin which allow us find out which children are affected by given parent's pom?

Comment: @DJ. Sorry if I misunderstood. I'm now confused about what you desire. Are you wanting a list of children that are currently using a parent with version x.y.x?

Comment: Sorry to confuse you Duncan. I'm just exploring the available options and trying to figure out what is the best and easiest way to handle this case. Either top-down or bottom-up.